# altering the default number of songs in upnext (itunes11, osx)?

Tags: macos, itunes

Currently I only see about 12 songs in upnext, not so great when I want to create a 3 hour playlist, but I can't find a setting anywhere to increase this.

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: Only on this site! Maybe because no one is answering my questions with a satisfactory response? i.e. One that actually answers the question I have asked not something different or only 20% of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a normal or intelligent playlist and play it. Do not use shuffle and you can add songs during playback.

Edit: If you *just* want to show more songs in upnext - it is not possible. But 12 Songs i s a plenty of view in the future....

Comment: What does this have to do with altering the number of songs showing in the 'upnext' window? Did you even read the question?

Comment: I read your question - and you said you want to create a 3h playlist (this is your end goal) so creating a normal playlist and adding songs to it will work (although up next will still show only 12 songs). But you accomplished your goal to have an 3h editable playlist.

Comment: Question title: altering the default number of songs in upnext

Comment: I edited the answer according to *your question* ....